# Jenkins is not able to pull the code from git from a public repository

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

Hi i am completely new to jenkins, by googling some how i have add webhook in git and its working perfectly like when ever i do commit it triggers a job , but in console i am seeing git not bale to fetch the code and throwing an error message ,will be helpfull if anyone will sort out this for me..

Error message

```
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/zulfikarayub/Fravega_FrontEnd.git
 > git.exe init C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Fravega_frontEnd # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/zulfikarayub/Fravega_FrontEnd.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.27.0.windows.1'
 > git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/zulfikarayub/Fravega_FrontEnd.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/zulfikarayub/Fravega_FrontEnd.git # timeout=10
 > git.exe config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Avoid second fetch
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 8ff5713a5e01dcbb366787c20d24df417a404398 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f 8ff5713a5e01dcbb366787c20d24df417a404398 # timeout=10
ERROR: Unable to retrieve commit message
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing unknown 8ff5713a5e01dcbb366787c20d24df417a404398
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectReader.open(ObjectReader.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.parseAny(RevWalk.java:917)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.parseCommit(RevWalk.java:827)
    at hudson.plugins.git.util.RevCommitRepositoryCallback.invoke(RevCommitRepositoryCallback.java:25)
    at hudson.plugins.git.util.RevCommitRepositoryCallback.invoke(RevCommitRepositoryCallback.java:13)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.AbstractGitAPIImpl.withRepository(AbstractGitAPIImpl.java:29)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.withRepository(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.printCommitMessageToLog(GitSCM.java:1386)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1355)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1206)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1894)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
 > git.exe rev-list --no-walk 315e98c5f65da818e7a443082dba221ec90db8fd # timeout=10
Finished: SUCCESS
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HdoR.png)

Comment: Did you add the Git plugin with your Jenkins plugins?

Comment: yes i have install , please find the attached screenshot for the same

Answer (score 0):

It might be issue with git plug-in , downgrade your plug-in and give a try,

https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-46628

as same issue seen in git plug-in v3.5.1

I have also tried your repository in v4.3.0 of git plug-in which is worked fine.

[image]

Comment: the issue is not in the project setup seems , but since you have mentioned to downgrade it , 4.3.0 but still the same , the problem is while triggering a build it show this  ERROR: Unable to retrieve commit message

Comment: Did anyone figure this issue out? I'm getting this same issue and can't downgrade beyond the git plugin 4.6.0